# Problem with reading values as certain types

Tags: ios, swift, macos

Let's say I have a file where data appears like that:

```
1 10 20 30
2 12 33 44
3  1  2 3*
```

What I'm trying to do is to read these values line by line and write them to an array I've created. The problem is that some numbers have this '*' sign which I am supposed to ignore. Basically I want my program to read '3*' and save it to my array as '3'(Float value).

This is my code so far

```
let contents = try! String(contentsOfFile: myFileName)
let lines = contents.split(separator:"\n")

let numberOfLines = lines.count

///day is my class with three variables
let days = (0...numberOfLines).map{ _ in day() }

for n in 0...(numberOfLines-1)
{
    let dataVar = lines[n].split(separator: " ")

    days[n].dayNumber = Int(dataVar[0])
    days[n].maxTemp = Float(dataVar[1])
    days[n].minTemp = Float(dataVar[2])
}

//here I print the numbers I've read before
for n in 0...(numberOfLines-1)
{
    print(days[n].dayNumber!)
    print(days[n].maxTemp!)
    print(days[n].minTemp!)
}
```

I create an object that represents each line (it's necessary for what I am gonna do later), I read the numbers and save them to my objects.

It works as long as these unwanted '*' appears. 
**How can I go through it?**

Comment: Is it always the `*` character? Will there be other characters that you need to ignore?

Comment: @Sweeper it is always the * character

Comment: What about doing `dataVar[x].replacingOccurrences(of: "*", with: "")` before converting it to an `Int` or `Float`?

Comment: `dataVar[x].replacingOccurrences(of: "[^0-9]*", with: "", options: .regularExpression)` will remove every character that is not a digit.

Comment: Ok I will try it and luk. Thank you.

Comment: @Sweeper It caused 'Result of call to 'replacingOccurrences(of:with:options:range:)' is unused' and also didn't work. Same issue when I reach the field with '3*'

Comment: @exxthc I mean something like `Int(dataVar[0].replacingOccurrences(of: "*", with: ""))`

Comment: Oh ya. I just did it 5secs ago and it worked out. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `*` by calling `replacingOccurrences(of:)` before converting the string to a `Float` or `Int`:

```
for n in 0...(numberOfLines-1)
{
    let dataVar = lines[n].split(separator: " ")

    days[n].dayNumber = Int(dataVar[0].replacingOccurrences(of: "*", with: ""))
    days[n].maxTemp = Float(dataVar[1].replacingOccurrences(of: "*", with: ""))
    days[n].minTemp = Float(dataVar[2].replacingOccurrences(of: "*", with: ""))
}
```